# How do I find out why my answer was down-voted

Tags: support, down-votes

Today an answer I posted ([Magento 1.9.1.1 Compatibility](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/197520/magento-1-9-1-1-compatibility/197548#197548)) was down-voted. I don't know why and I can't see how to find out. Is it possible to know why?

Comment: why do you want to know who downvoted your answer?

Comment: So I can ask them why they down voted it. I'm curious because I can't see why they did it. If I have provided a poor answer I want to know how to improve.

Comment: Actually eh moral thing to do when one downvotes a post is to leave a comment below the post explaining the downvote, but people cannot be forced to do so.

Comment: Maybe it should be made mandatory to leave a comment if downvoting.

Comment: I think there was a discussion about this on meta.stackexchange.com, but not sure. The result was that it will not be mandatory.

Comment: I'm going to do the moral thing and explain why I downvoted *this question*. It boils down to "how can I know what someone else was thinking while clicking a button on the internet". This is a question that cannot be answered, you will have to live with it. The only advice I can give is to not take it personally.

Comment: @fabian Now we're getting into semantics and the vagueries of the English language ;-) All I wanted to know was how to find out who, and hence why, something was down voted. Clearly not possible unless someone has morals. I don't take it personally. I have to say though that stackexchange is not geared for friendliness towards the uninitiated, those who don't know the nuances of the rules, and those for whom English is not their first language.

Comment: Downvote here, upvote there :P

Comment: @jscar, Even on this question also you got downvote. Oh god !

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara :o) I love stackexchange! It's definitely not for people with self-worth problems.

Answer (score 0):

**Not possible** only the down voter can tell you reason why he did that.